# How HTTP request in Golang attaches cert.pem and key.pem?

Tags: go

I'm using golang and want my request to attach `apiclient_cert.p12`.

After searching from internet, I find golang doesn't support decoding `file.p12`.So I transfer `apiclient.p12` into `cert.pem` and `key.pem`.

Now I've know `cert.pem` and `key.pem` path. How to use it in golang http request.

Comment: [this gist](https://gist.github.com/denji/12b3a568f092ab951456) looks promising

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load the certificate files using [tls.LoadX509KeyPair](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/tls/#LoadX509KeyPair), and create a [tls.Config](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/tls/#Config) which has the loaded certificate in its `Certificates` slice. Make an [http.Transport](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Transport) which has that config as its `TLSClientConfig`, and make an [http.Client](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Client) which has that transport as its `Transport`. Finally, make requests using that client!